# Android calendar color from 'CALENDAR_COLOR' differ from real calendar color

Tags: android, colors, calendar

I get the color using column `CALENDAR_COLOR` as `int`, but the color is different then the real one displayed in the calendar.
In fact, it's similar color, but much lighter ! Any reason why that happens?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using DDMS to take a screenshot of the color you want, then use paint or photoshop to get that color, then set that color manually.

Comment: I don't want a manual setting, I want the color to match by getting the true one, what if new colors will be added to the system ?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue. I thought the colour difference is a result of some function which could be reversed. However, I wasn't able to find it the change doesn't seem to be consistent.

Comment: @jurer, I've looked over Google Calendar code and noticed the are using Color DB to get and set calendars / event colors. I must say I thought it's an overkill so I just left the current implementation.

Comment: Thanks for replying to such an old thread. That's interesting, though shouldn't the colours be the same? Could you please point me to a reference? I just discovered the Google Calendar app for older Android (Kitkat and older) displays the same colours that I get (brighter than on newer Google Calendar). It appears as though the new Calendar app used some Material styling.

Comment: Try looking over this repository:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-cts-6.0_r1/src/com/android/calendar

Comment: Thanks, I did yesterday and I discovered that the colour is indeed being changed for on newer Android releases here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3/src/com/android/calendar/agenda/AgendaAdapter.java#181

I'm applying the same filter on my colours and for some calendars the results are close (though not the same), unfortunately calendars from 'More' categeory in the Calendar app have completely different colours.

Answer (score 6):

The Google calendar app makes a transformation on the colors. It uses a hardcoded map to search for color correspondence. If the color is not found on the map, it applies a manual transformation.

This is a simplified (but functional) version of the code:

```
public final class CalendarUtils {

private static final Map<Integer, Integer> sUpdatedColors;

static {
    Map hashMap = new HashMap();
    sUpdatedColors = hashMap;
    hashMap.put(-509406, -2818048);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-370884, -765666);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-35529, -1086464);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-21178, -1010944);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-339611, -606426);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-267901, -1784767);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4989844, -4142541);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8662712, -8604862);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-15292571, -16023485);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12396910, -16738680);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-7151168, -13388167);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-6299161, -16540699);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-6306073, -12417548);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-11958553, -12627531);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-6644481, -8812853);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4613377, -5005861);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5997854, -6395473);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3312410, -7461718);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3365204, -5434281);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-618062, -2614432);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3118236, -1672077);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5475746, -8825528);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4013374, -10395295);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-3490369, -5792882);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2350809, -2818048);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-18312, -765666);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-272549, -606426);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-11421879, -16023485);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8722497, -13388167);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12134693, -16540699);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-11238163, -12627531);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5980676, -8812853);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2380289, -7461718);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-30596, -1672077);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1973791, -10395295);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2883584, -2818048);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-831459, -765666);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1152256, -1086464);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1076736, -1010944);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-672219, -606426);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1914036, -1784767);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-4208334, -4142541);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8670655, -8604862);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-16089278, -16023485);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-16738937, -16738680);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-16606492, -16540699);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12483341, -12417548);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-12624727, -12627531);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8878646, -8812853);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5071654, -5005861);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-7527511, -7461718);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-5500074, -5434281);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-2680225, -2614432);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-1737870, -1672077);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-8891321, -8825528);
    sUpdatedColors.put(-10263709, -10395295);
}

public static int getDisplayColor(int color) {
    if (sUpdatedColors.containsKey(color)) {
        return (sUpdatedColors.get(color));
    }
    if (sUpdatedColors.containsValue(color)) {
        return color;
    }
    float[] fArr = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, fArr);
    if (fArr[2] > 0.79f) {
        fArr[1] = Math.min(fArr[1] * 1.3f, 1.0f);
        fArr[2] = fArr[2] * 0.8f;
    }
    return Color.HSVToColor(Color.alpha(color), fArr);
}

}
```

To obtain the transformed color, you can call the getDisplayColor(color) method using the color returned by the Calendar Provider (as the Calendar Provider returns a string, we need to parse it to an integer before):

```
int calendarColor = Integer.parseInt(colorStringFromCalendarProvider);
int transformedColor = CalendarUtils.getDisplayColor(calendarColor);
```

Comment: This is great, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: No, the last published calendar source (https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar) only contains a manual transformation (see their getDisplayColorFromColor method). But I took a peek at the current calendar apk to find the map color correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize variable**

```
private View mView;
```

**Bind view with variable**

```
mView = (View) findViewById(R.id.mView);
```

**Calendar content provider will return color code, you have to write code to get color code of Calendar**

```
String calendarColorCode = "-5997854";
```

**Convert int color**

```
int mColorCode = (0xff000000 + Integer.parseInt(calendarColorCode));
```

**Apply background color code on view**

```
viewColorCode.setBackgroundColor(mColorCode);
```

**Done !**

Comment: For information: calendarColorCode is CALENDAR_COLOR from event (CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_COLOR) instead from calendar (CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR)! After this suggestion works for me.

Comment: unfortunately the color does not match with the same in Google Calendar :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also use as string, as long as it is a ARGB valid code, like *"0xFF005500"*.

ARGB stands for Alpha / Red / Green / Blue, knowing this you can easily convert a HEX (Which is RGB) code like #FF8866 into ARGB 0xFFFF8866.

In the example given, Red code will be FF, Green code will be 88 and Blue code will be 66. This will be an opaque color by default, so will assign FF as alpha, resulting the ARGB code of 0xFFFF8866.